# How use instead of comma in mapped list

Tags: python, list, mapping, python-3.10

My code--

```py
match key:
    case list(map(ord, map( str, range(1,10) )):
        #...
```

> this map function makes this format--
> `[ord('1'), ord('2'), ord('3'), ...]` from 1 to 9

But want like `[ord('1') | ord('2') | ...]`

How can i do that?

Comment: I don't want to write the *list manually. Cause the range can be increase

Comment: Which part of the code you show produces that output??

Comment: So... You want the actual value of the list using pipes, or you wish to print it out as pipes, or what?

Comment: @AgentBiscutt Good question, and still: There is no *"the list"* in what the op shows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
match key:
    case key if key in map(ord, map( str, range(1,10))):
        #...
```

Note: instead of double `map` use a comprehension:

```
>>> [ord(str(i)) for i in range(1, 10)]
[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57]
```